# Parametric integral over a circle

Tags: multivariable-calculus, line-integrals

Let us live in $\mathbb{R^2}$, $\vec{e_1} = \vec{(1,0)}, \vec{e_2} = \vec{(0,1)}$ are two standard vectors.

> Evaluate $\Large{\int_{C_1} \frac{y\vec{e_1}-x\vec{e_2}}{x^2+y^2} d\vec{r}}$ where $C_1$ is a circle of radius $3$ centered at $(0,0)$

I am completely stuck.

Comment: Can you find a parametric equation for the contour?

Comment: What are the vector arrows over i and j supposed to mean?

Comment: That represents the slope field

Comment: Please type out images. Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: let x = 3cost, y=3sint, integrate from 0 to 2pi

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp $\mathbf{i}$ and $\mathbf{j}$ traditionally represent the vectors $\langle 1,0\rangle$ and $\langle 0,1\rangle$, respectively (I'm using bold rather than an arrow over them). So the question is asking one to evaluate $\int_{C_1}\!\mathbf{F}\cdot d\mathbf{r}$, where $\mathbf{F}$ is the vector field defined by $\mathbf{F}(x,y) = \langle\frac{y}{x^2 + y^2},\frac{-x}{x^2 + y^2}\rangle$.

Comment: I'm gonna take a guess and say greens theorem

Answer (score 3):

Just straight parametrization is not that difficult. Assume positive orientation. Parametrize as follows,

$$\vec r(t)=\langle 3 \cos (t),  3\sin (t) \rangle$$

Or if you prefer $x=3\cos (t)$, and $y=3 \sin (t)$.

Then,

$$\vec dr=\langle -3 \sin (t),3\cos (t) \rangle dt$$

We have $x^2+y^2=9$ on our curve so we just need to evaluate,

$$\int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{1}{9} \langle 3\sin (t), -3\cos (t) \rangle \cdot \langle -3 \sin (t), 3 \cos t \rangle dt$$

$$=\int_{0}^{2\pi} -1 dt$$

$$=-2\pi$$

It is possible to [prove](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/394816/line-integral-of-every-positively-oriented-simple-closed-path-greens-theorem) the result holds for any closed, simple, curve $C$ enclosing the origin by creating a slit that avoids the origin and connects to a circle centered at the origin which is of radius $a$, then by using Greens Theorem.

Answer (score 2):

In polar coordinates $(r,\theta)$, we have

$$\begin{align}
\color{blue}{\left(\frac{y\vec i -x\vec j}{x^2+y^2}\right)}\cdot \color{red}{d\vec r}&=\color{blue}{\left(\frac{-r\,\hat \theta}{r^2}\right)}\cdot \color{red}{\hat \theta \,r\,d\theta}\\\\
&=-\,d\theta
\end{align}$$

Therefore, we can write

$$\begin{align}
\oint_{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=3}\frac{y\vec i -x\vec j}{x^2+y^2}\cdot d\vec r&=\int_0^{2\pi}(-1)\,d\theta\\\\
&=-2\pi
\end{align}$$

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve my answer. I really want to give you the best answer I can.  -Mark

Comment: Dear Mark, could you explain to me the equality in the first sentence? Particularly, what is $\hat{\theta}$?

Comment: Sure.  $\theta$ is the polar angle such that $\sin(\theta)=y/\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ and $\cos (\theta)=x/\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$.